# Laravel- Create Archive and download the files from Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am looking for more of a better approach here. I have an app developed in `Laravel` that stores images on `AWS S3`, then users can download the images. My process is as follows

- Operators upload the pictures, low quality thumbnails are created on the fly and stored on server while original images are uploaded to S3
- Users come on the site and they can download pictures by **ALL** or **One by One**
- One by one thing works fine as it downloads directly from S3 to the user's system
- When user requests for **Download All**, it first fetches all the images from S3 to my server, creates a zip and then download the zipped file.

Both scenarios are working fine but in **Download All** case, ti takes too much time as some times there is more than 1gb of data to be downloaded.

Is there any better approach to do this? Like I could request for the zip and when its ready I should get an alert or any other suggestion to make this approach better

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Async Transfer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-transfer.html#async-transfers) in which the transfer can be initiated using `promise` and use `then` to notify.